# Is "catch up" used in formal language as in "We will catch up sometime"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, formality, phrasal-verbs

I wrote "we will catch up sometime" to one of my new friends. When I searched the Internet I found that people used it in informal situations. Is it okay to use this in formal writing as I did since the friendship is very new? What else could I have used? I tend to think that the answer depends on culture.

My purpose in context:

I want to put the decision of when and where to meet, to the other person.

Comment: I found many examples in different usages but all informal as you can easily find in "urban dictionary". What was your context and what did you want to say by this?

Comment: I want to put the decision of when and where to meet, to the other person.

Comment: Ok! It is better now!

Comment: So after edit I found it better but anyway my guess was correct about your mean. Personally I do not like a new friend/or a person who tries to be a friend of mine tells me that and prefer your last sentence after edit! Yes, You answered yourself. :)

Comment: Personally, I would say "I hope we can reconnect very soon," but that doesn't convey the new-ness of your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "catch up with" is considered--currently at least--informal but standard English.
More formal English would be "let us set up an appointment". However, if this is an informal setting, meeting a friend, then "catch up with" is fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are several meanings and synonyms according to the usages in the contexts. Do you mean you will see each other very soon like the usage in "catch you later"? I think it depends on your purpose and audience according to the context.

There are some like [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/catch+up?__utma=1.369963783.1360149629.1360587811.1360598260.4&__utmb=1.1.10.1360598260&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1360149629.1.1.utmcsr=%28direct%29%7Cutmccn=%28direct%29%7Cutmcmd=%28none%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=11352500) and [here](http://thesaurus.com/browse/catch+up)

I hope it helps but I think if you provide more contexts, you might find better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I might say "Let's get in touch soon."  That is informal and even personal, but it allows for this to be a new friend.  I would not use "catch-up" yet, because that implies you are updating previously shared information.
As you have not yet had the initial meeting, to "update" each other is not accurate.

I hope this helps clarify the meaning of "catch-up" by using and explaining a counter-example.